# Adding subtitles in react native video

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I went through the react-native props and come to know they added **selectedTextTrack** for subtitle support. But, how exactly it can be added I'm unable to write code.
Can I add a file(.SRT) as input for a subtitle?

```js
<Video
  source={{uri: ''}}
  resizeMode={this.state.resizeMode}
  style={mediaPlayerStyle.player}
  rate={this.state.rate}
  volume={this.state.volume}
  paused={this.state.paused}
  onLoad={this.onLoad}
  onProgress={this.onProgress}
  onEnd={this.onEnd}
  repeat={true}
  selectedTextTrack={{
    type: 'index',
    value: 0
  }}
  textTracks={[
    {
      index: 0,
      title: "English CC",
      language: "en",
      type: TextTrackType.VTT, // "text/vtt"
      uri: "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/subtitles/subtitles_en.vtt"
    },
    {
      index: 1,
      title: "Spanish Subtitles",
      language: "es",
      type: TextTrackType.SRT, // "application/x-subrip"
      uri: "https://durian.blender.org/wp-content/content/subtitles/sintel_es.srt"
    }
  ]}
/>
```

So basically i want to add subtitles for one video in various languages, If it is .srt file that would be a great help

Comment: Did you find a solution where you could work with .srt as a local file? (not web-hosted)

Comment: @EugeneKovalev no, i didn't. Do you know how to use web-hosted file?

Comment: @Subham just add the following to <Video>

selectedTextTrack={{
                        type: "title",
                        value: "English CC"
                    }}
                    textTracks={[
                        {
                            title: "English CC",
                            language: "en",
                            type: TextTrackType.VTT,
                            uri: "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/subtitles/subtitles_en.vtt"
                        }
                    ]}

Comment: The problem is it will make impossible to use the app offline

Answer (score -1):

use react-native-video-controls that renders subtitles on top of the video using JavaScript, which you might try.

In order to use subtitles you should follow the below instructions : First if your subtitle format is srt you should convert it to JSON(use websites like : http://multiverso.me/srtToJSON/) Then when you got the array of JSONs, you can pass this array to VideoPlayer as below :

```
<VideoPlayer subtitle={this.props.subtitle}/>
```

The subtitle prop expects the JSON to have the following key-value format:

```
[{
   "startTime": "00:00:04,123", //hh:mm:ss,SSS
   "endTime": "00:00:05,001",
   "text": "When you convert your subtitle file, you might need to modify your JSON"
},
{
   "startTime": "00:00:08,008",
   "endTime": "00:00:09,876",
   "text": "Before passing it to the VidePlayer component"
}]
```

Comment: thanks for you reply! But, as you can see i am using react-native-video  and have tried with .srt  and  .vtt  format. still i'm unable to get results as it was mention here https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/1044

Comment: It's a nice lib. But subtitles didn't work for me and no info about `subtitle` in the repo. Any thoughts on this?